# Mongo process crashed every few days on windows

Tags: mongodb, windows, windows-services, windbg

I have used MongoDB on Linux several times, and this is the first time I used it on Windows. Since there are other similar applications running on Linux and all of them looks well, I suspect this problem would happen only on Windows. Here is the command I executed:

```
net start MongoDB
```

The mongoDB service stopped after the following error displayed in log file.

> The environment is `Windows Server 2019 Standard 64 bit` and `Mongo 5.0 Community`

#### mongod.log

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.007+08:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4757800, "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Writing fatal message","attr":{"message":"terminate() called. An exception is active; attempting to gather more information"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.007+08:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4757800, "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Writing fatal message","attr":{"message":"DBException::toString(): FileRenameFailed: \ufffds\ufffd\ufffd\ufffdQ\ufffdڡC\nActual exception type: class mongo::error_details::ExceptionForImpl<37,class mongo::AssertionException>\n"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.360+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31380,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"BACKTRACE","attr":{"bt":{"backtrace":[{"a":"7FF77FDF31B3","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/util/stacktrace_windows.cpp","line":321,"s":"mongo::`anonymous namespace'::printWindowsStackTraceImpl","s+":"43"},{"a":"7FF77FDF62EB","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/util/signal_handlers_synchronous.cpp","line":226,"s":"mongo::`anonymous namespace'::myTerminate","s+":"BB"},{"a":"7FF77FEBFA67","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/stdx/set_terminate_internals.cpp","line":88,"s":"mongo::stdx::dispatch_impl","s+":"17"},{"a":"7FF77FEBFA49","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/stdx/set_terminate_internals.cpp","line":92,"s":"mongo::stdx::TerminateHandlerDetailsInterface::dispatch","s+":"9"},{"a":"7FFDE8AADE58","module":"ucrtbase.dll","s":"terminate","s+":"18"},{"a":"7FFDD6EE1ABF","module":"VCRUNTIME140_1.dll","s":"_NLG_Return2","s+":"96F"},{"a":"7FFDD6EE232B","module":"VCRUNTIME140_1.dll","s":"_NLG_Return2","s+":"11DB"},{"a":"7FFDD6EE40E9","module":"VCRUNTIME140_1.dll","s":"_CxxFrameHandler4","s+":"A9"},{"a":"7FF7800BBB48","module":"mongod.exe","file":"d:/A01/_work/6/s/src/vctools/crt/vcstartup/src/gs/amd64/gshandlereh4.cpp","line":86,"s":"__GSHandlerCheck_EH4","s+":"64"},{"a":"7FFDEC4B4A2F","module":"ntdll.dll","s":"_chkstk","s+":"11F"},{"a":"7FFDEC414CEF","module":"ntdll.dll","s":"RtlWalkFrameChain","s+":"14BF"},{"a":"7FFDEC418AE6","module":"ntdll.dll","s":"RtlRaiseException","s+":"316"},{"a":"7FFDE8529329","module":"KERNELBASE.dll","s":"RaiseException","s+":"69"},{"a":"7FFDD5676210","module":"VCRUNTIME140.dll","s":"CxxThrowException","s+":"90"},{"a":"7FF77FE6C92D","module":"mongod.exe","file":"C:/data/mci/e46f1a17206528956f3466ce347a3323/src/build/opt/mongo/base/error_codes.cpp","line":2270,"s":"mongo::error_details::throwExceptionForStatus","s+":"42D"},{"a":"7FF77FE00604","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/util/assert_util.cpp","line":260,"s":"mongo::uassertedWithLocation","s+":"184"},{"a":"7FF77E7B76DD","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/ftdc/controller.cpp","line":254,"s":"mongo::FTDCController::doLoop","s+":"5BD"},{"a":"7FF77E7B6FBC","module":"mongod.exe","file":"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/include/thread","line":44,"s":"std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<<lambda_726633d7e71a0bdccc2c30a401264d8c> >,0>","s+":"2C"},{"a":"7FFDE8A6268A","module":"ucrtbase.dll","s":"o_exp","s+":"5A"},{"a":"7FFDE9777974","module":"KERNEL32.DLL","s":"BaseThreadInitThunk","s+":"14"}]}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.360+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF77FDF31B3","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/util/stacktrace_windows.cpp","line":321,"s":"mongo::`anonymous namespace'::printWindowsStackTraceImpl","s+":"43"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.360+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF77FDF62EB","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/util/signal_handlers_synchronous.cpp","line":226,"s":"mongo::`anonymous namespace'::myTerminate","s+":"BB"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.360+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF77FEBFA67","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/stdx/set_terminate_internals.cpp","line":88,"s":"mongo::stdx::dispatch_impl","s+":"17"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.360+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF77FEBFA49","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/stdx/set_terminate_internals.cpp","line":92,"s":"mongo::stdx::TerminateHandlerDetailsInterface::dispatch","s+":"9"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.360+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FFDE8AADE58","module":"ucrtbase.dll","s":"terminate","s+":"18"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.360+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FFDD6EE1ABF","module":"VCRUNTIME140_1.dll","s":"_NLG_Return2","s+":"96F"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.360+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FFDD6EE232B","module":"VCRUNTIME140_1.dll","s":"_NLG_Return2","s+":"11DB"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.360+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FFDD6EE40E9","module":"VCRUNTIME140_1.dll","s":"_CxxFrameHandler4","s+":"A9"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.360+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF7800BBB48","module":"mongod.exe","file":"d:/A01/_work/6/s/src/vctools/crt/vcstartup/src/gs/amd64/gshandlereh4.cpp","line":86,"s":"__GSHandlerCheck_EH4","s+":"64"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.360+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FFDEC4B4A2F","module":"ntdll.dll","s":"_chkstk","s+":"11F"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.360+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FFDEC414CEF","module":"ntdll.dll","s":"RtlWalkFrameChain","s+":"14BF"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.360+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FFDEC418AE6","module":"ntdll.dll","s":"RtlRaiseException","s+":"316"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.360+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FFDE8529329","module":"KERNELBASE.dll","s":"RaiseException","s+":"69"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.360+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FFDD5676210","module":"VCRUNTIME140.dll","s":"CxxThrowException","s+":"90"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.360+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF77FE6C92D","module":"mongod.exe","file":"C:/data/mci/e46f1a17206528956f3466ce347a3323/src/build/opt/mongo/base/error_codes.cpp","line":2270,"s":"mongo::error_details::throwExceptionForStatus","s+":"42D"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.360+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF77FE00604","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/util/assert_util.cpp","line":260,"s":"mongo::uassertedWithLocation","s+":"184"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.360+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF77E7B76DD","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/ftdc/controller.cpp","line":254,"s":"mongo::FTDCController::doLoop","s+":"5BD"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.360+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF77E7B6FBC","module":"mongod.exe","file":"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/include/thread","line":44,"s":"std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<<lambda_726633d7e71a0bdccc2c30a401264d8c> >,0>","s+":"2C"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.360+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FFDE8A6268A","module":"ucrtbase.dll","s":"o_exp","s+":"5A"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.360+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FFDE9777974","module":"KERNEL32.DLL","s":"BaseThreadInitThunk","s+":"14"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.360+08:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23134,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Unhandled exception","attr":{"exceptionString":"0xE0000001","addressString":"0x00007FFDE8529329"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.360+08:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23136,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"*** stack trace for unhandled exception:"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.361+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31380,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"BACKTRACE","attr":{"bt":{"backtrace":[{"a":"7FFDE8529329","module":"KERNELBASE.dll","s":"RaiseException","s+":"69"},{"a":"7FF77FDF5AC9","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/util/signal_handlers_synchronous.cpp","line":99,"s":"mongo::`anonymous namespace'::endProcessWithSignal","s+":"19"},{"a":"7FF77FDF62FA","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/util/signal_handlers_synchronous.cpp","line":227,"s":"mongo::`anonymous namespace'::myTerminate","s+":"CA"},{"a":"7FF77FEBFA67","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/stdx/set_terminate_internals.cpp","line":88,"s":"mongo::stdx::dispatch_impl","s+":"17"},{"a":"7FF77FEBFA49","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/stdx/set_terminate_internals.cpp","line":92,"s":"mongo::stdx::TerminateHandlerDetailsInterface::dispatch","s+":"9"},{"a":"7FFDE8AADE58","module":"ucrtbase.dll","s":"terminate","s+":"18"},{"a":"7FFDD6EE1ABF","module":"VCRUNTIME140_1.dll","s":"_NLG_Return2","s+":"96F"},{"a":"7FFDD6EE232B","module":"VCRUNTIME140_1.dll","s":"_NLG_Return2","s+":"11DB"},{"a":"7FFDD6EE40E9","module":"VCRUNTIME140_1.dll","s":"_CxxFrameHandler4","s+":"A9"},{"a":"7FF7800BBB48","module":"mongod.exe","file":"d:/A01/_work/6/s/src/vctools/crt/vcstartup/src/gs/amd64/gshandlereh4.cpp","line":86,"s":"__GSHandlerCheck_EH4","s+":"64"},{"a":"7FFDEC4B4A2F","module":"ntdll.dll","s":"_chkstk","s+":"11F"},{"a":"7FFDEC414CEF","module":"ntdll.dll","s":"RtlWalkFrameChain","s+":"14BF"},{"a":"7FFDEC418AE6","module":"ntdll.dll","s":"RtlRaiseException","s+":"316"},{"a":"7FFDE8529329","module":"KERNELBASE.dll","s":"RaiseException","s+":"69"},{"a":"7FFDD5676210","module":"VCRUNTIME140.dll","s":"CxxThrowException","s+":"90"},{"a":"7FF77FE6C92D","module":"mongod.exe","file":"C:/data/mci/e46f1a17206528956f3466ce347a3323/src/build/opt/mongo/base/error_codes.cpp","line":2270,"s":"mongo::error_details::throwExceptionForStatus","s+":"42D"},{"a":"7FF77FE00604","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/util/assert_util.cpp","line":260,"s":"mongo::uassertedWithLocation","s+":"184"},{"a":"7FF77E7B76DD","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/ftdc/controller.cpp","line":254,"s":"mongo::FTDCController::doLoop","s+":"5BD"},{"a":"7FF77E7B6FBC","module":"mongod.exe","file":"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/include/thread","line":44,"s":"std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<<lambda_726633d7e71a0bdccc2c30a401264d8c> >,0>","s+":"2C"},{"a":"7FFDE8A6268A","module":"ucrtbase.dll","s":"o_exp","s+":"5A"},{"a":"7FFDE9777974","module":"KERNEL32.DLL","s":"BaseThreadInitThunk","s+":"14"}]}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.361+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FFDE8529329","module":"KERNELBASE.dll","s":"RaiseException","s+":"69"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.361+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF77FDF5AC9","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/util/signal_handlers_synchronous.cpp","line":99,"s":"mongo::`anonymous namespace'::endProcessWithSignal","s+":"19"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.361+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF77FDF62FA","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/util/signal_handlers_synchronous.cpp","line":227,"s":"mongo::`anonymous namespace'::myTerminate","s+":"CA"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.361+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF77FEBFA67","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/stdx/set_terminate_internals.cpp","line":88,"s":"mongo::stdx::dispatch_impl","s+":"17"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.361+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF77FEBFA49","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/stdx/set_terminate_internals.cpp","line":92,"s":"mongo::stdx::TerminateHandlerDetailsInterface::dispatch","s+":"9"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.361+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FFDE8AADE58","module":"ucrtbase.dll","s":"terminate","s+":"18"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.361+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FFDD6EE1ABF","module":"VCRUNTIME140_1.dll","s":"_NLG_Return2","s+":"96F"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.361+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FFDD6EE232B","module":"VCRUNTIME140_1.dll","s":"_NLG_Return2","s+":"11DB"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.361+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FFDD6EE40E9","module":"VCRUNTIME140_1.dll","s":"_CxxFrameHandler4","s+":"A9"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.361+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF7800BBB48","module":"mongod.exe","file":"d:/A01/_work/6/s/src/vctools/crt/vcstartup/src/gs/amd64/gshandlereh4.cpp","line":86,"s":"__GSHandlerCheck_EH4","s+":"64"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.361+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FFDEC4B4A2F","module":"ntdll.dll","s":"_chkstk","s+":"11F"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.361+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FFDEC414CEF","module":"ntdll.dll","s":"RtlWalkFrameChain","s+":"14BF"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.361+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FFDEC418AE6","module":"ntdll.dll","s":"RtlRaiseException","s+":"316"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.361+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FFDE8529329","module":"KERNELBASE.dll","s":"RaiseException","s+":"69"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.361+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FFDD5676210","module":"VCRUNTIME140.dll","s":"CxxThrowException","s+":"90"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.361+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF77FE6C92D","module":"mongod.exe","file":"C:/data/mci/e46f1a17206528956f3466ce347a3323/src/build/opt/mongo/base/error_codes.cpp","line":2270,"s":"mongo::error_details::throwExceptionForStatus","s+":"42D"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.361+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF77FE00604","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/util/assert_util.cpp","line":260,"s":"mongo::uassertedWithLocation","s+":"184"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.361+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF77E7B76DD","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/ftdc/controller.cpp","line":254,"s":"mongo::FTDCController::doLoop","s+":"5BD"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.361+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF77E7B6FBC","module":"mongod.exe","file":"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/include/thread","line":44,"s":"std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<<lambda_726633d7e71a0bdccc2c30a401264d8c> >,0>","s+":"2C"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.361+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FFDE8A6268A","module":"ucrtbase.dll","s":"o_exp","s+":"5A"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.361+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FFDE9777974","module":"KERNEL32.DLL","s":"BaseThreadInitThunk","s+":"14"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.361+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23132,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Writing minidump diagnostic file","attr":{"dumpName":"C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB\\Server\\5.0\\bin\\mongod.2021-10-20T16-34-58.mdmp"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-21T00:34:58.431+08:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23137,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"*** immediate exit due to unhandled exception"}
```

I've surveyed about the `DBException::toString(): FileRenameFailed`, but most of the resources online are about file permissions, and it's already been fixed. According to the error log, it seems more like an encoding problem.

I also opened the `C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB\\Server\\5.0\\bin\\mongod.2021-10-20T16-34-58.mdmp` mentioned in `mongod.log` by WinDbg. And here's what I get:

#### mongod.2021-10-20T16-34-58.mdmp

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.22000.194 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\bin\mongod.2021-10-20T16-34-58.mdmp]
User Mini Dump File: Only registers, stack and portions of memory are available

Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Version 17763 MP (16 procs) Free x64
Product: Server, suite: TerminalServer
Edition build lab: 17763.1.amd64fre.rs5_release.180914-1434
Machine Name:
Debug session time: Thu Oct 21 00:34:58.000 2021 (UTC + 8:00)
System Uptime: not available
Process Uptime: 7 days 10:20:33.000
............................................
This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(3100.1cb4): Unknown exception - code e0000001 (first/second chance not available)
For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
ntdll!NtGetContextThread+0x14:
00007ffd`ec4b1764 c3              ret
0:023> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for mongod.exe

KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
    Value: 1453

    Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisManager
    Value: Create

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 5554

    Key  : Analysis.Init.CPU.mSec
    Value: 687

    Key  : Analysis.Init.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 10747

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 167

    Key  : Timeline.Process.Start.DeltaSec
    Value: 642033

    Key  : WER.OS.Branch
    Value: rs5_release

    Key  : WER.OS.Timestamp
    Value: 2018-09-14T14:34:00Z

    Key  : WER.OS.Version
    Value: 10.0.17763.1

    Key  : WER.Process.Version
    Value: 5.0.3.0


NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

CONTEXT:  (.ecxr)
rax=0000015da9dd7dc8 rbx=0000000000000001 rcx=0000015daa13d9c0
rdx=0000015da9dd7db0 rsi=0000002009afe830 rdi=00000000ffffffff
rip=00007ffde8529329 rsp=0000002009afdd30 rbp=0000002009afe040
 r8=0000015da9dd7db0  r9=0000000000000000 r10=0000000000000018
r11=0000000000000000 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000002009afe9f0
r14=0000002009afe1f0 r15=0000002009afe220
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000206
KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x69:
00007ffd`e8529329 0f1f440000      nop     dword ptr [rax+rax]
Resetting default scope

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 00007ffde8529329 (KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x0000000000000069)
   ExceptionCode: e0000001
  ExceptionFlags: 00000001
NumberParameters: 0

PROCESS_NAME:  mongod.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xe0000001 - <Unable to get error code text>

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  e0000001

STACK_TEXT:  
00000020`09afdd30 00007ff7`7fdf5ac9     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00007ff7`7fddf88a : KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x69
00000020`09afde10 00007ff7`7fdf62fa     : 00000000`00000001 00007ff7`80d40ec0 00000020`09afe830 00000000`ffffffff : mongod!mozPoisonValueInit+0x3cd3d9
00000020`09afde60 00007ff7`7febfa67     : 00000000`00000006 00007ffd`e8a4fb00 0000d61f`00000005 00007ff7`80390479 : mongod!mozPoisonValueInit+0x3cdc0a
00000020`09afdeb0 00007ff7`7febfa49     : 00000020`09afe220 00000020`09afe1f0 00000000`00000000 00000000`ffffffff : mongod!tcmalloc::Sampler::operator=+0xc0e37
00000020`09afdee0 00007ffd`e8aade58     : 0000015d`a9d42080 00000020`09aff890 00000020`09afe040 0000015d`a9d42080 : mongod!tcmalloc::Sampler::operator=+0xc0e19
00000020`09afdf10 00007ffd`d6ee1abf     : 00000020`09aff890 00000020`09afe830 00000020`09afe1f0 00000020`09afe1f0 : ucrtbase!terminate+0x18
00000020`09afdf40 00007ffd`d6ee232b     : 00000000`00000005 00007ffd`d569bf1a 00000000`00000001 00007ffd`d5672279 : VCRUNTIME140_1!FindHandler<__FrameHandler4>+0x46f
00000020`09afe110 00007ffd`d6ee40e9     : 00007ff7`7e390000 00000020`09aff890 00000020`09afe9f0 00000020`09afe830 : VCRUNTIME140_1!__InternalCxxFrameHandler<__FrameHandler4>+0x267
00000020`09afe1b0 00007ff7`800bbb48     : 00000020`09affb30 00007ff7`80b064ec 00000020`09aff890 00000020`09affb30 : VCRUNTIME140_1!__CxxFrameHandler4+0xa9
00000020`09afe220 00007ffd`ec4b4a2f     : 00000000`00000000 00000020`09afe7c0 00000000`00000001 00007ff7`7e390000 : mongod!tcmalloc::Log+0x1ee608
00000020`09afe250 00007ffd`ec414cef     : 00000020`09afe7c0 00000000`00000001 00007ff7`813092cc 00007ff7`7e390000 : ntdll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException+0xf
00000020`09afe280 00007ffd`ec418ae6     : 00000020`09afe9f0 00007ffd`ec4188d1 00000020`09afe9f0 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlDispatchException+0x40f
00000020`09afe9b0 00007ffd`e8529329     : 00000020`09aff860 00007ff7`80d1e490 00000020`09aff9d0 00000000`19930520 : ntdll!RtlRaiseException+0x316
00000020`09aff870 00007ffd`d5676210     : 00000020`09aff9d0 00000020`09aff9d0 0000015d`a778bdb0 00000000`00000000 : KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x69
00000020`09aff950 00007ff7`7fe6c92d     : 0000015d`9bcde2c8 00000020`09affb60 0000015d`9bcde2c8 00000020`09affb60 : VCRUNTIME140!_CxxThrowException+0x90
00000020`09aff9b0 00007ff7`7fe00604     : 0000015d`a9a3b4d0 00000000`00000005 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : mongod!tcmalloc::Sampler::operator=+0x6dcfd
00000020`09affa30 00007ff7`7e7b76dd     : 0000015d`a9b4b5d0 0000015d`a9a3b4d0 00000020`000000fe 0000015d`a9a3b4d0 : mongod!tcmalloc::Sampler::operator=+0x19d4
00000020`09affb30 00007ff7`7e7b6fbc     : 00000000`00000000 0000015d`a9a3b4d0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : mongod!tcmalloc::StackTraceTable::~StackTraceTable+0x162aad
00000020`09affc60 00007ffd`e8a6268a     : 00000000`00000000 0000015d`a9b50890 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : mongod!tcmalloc::StackTraceTable::~StackTraceTable+0x16238c
00000020`09affc90 00007ffd`e9777974     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ucrtbase!thread_start<unsigned int (__cdecl*)(void * __ptr64)>+0x3a
00000020`09affcc0 00007ffd`ec46a2f1     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
00000020`09affcf0 00000000`00000000     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21


SYMBOL_NAME:  KERNELBASE!RaiseException+69

MODULE_NAME: KERNELBASE

IMAGE_NAME:  KERNELBASE.dll

STACK_COMMAND:  ~23s ; .ecxr ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_FAULT_e0000001_KERNELBASE.dll!RaiseException

OS_VERSION:  10.0.17763.1

BUILDLAB_STR:  rs5_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.17763.2028

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {15f4714e-4497-bb0c-6557-4f288161ec4c}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------

0:023> .exr -1
ExceptionAddress: 00007ffde8529329 (KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x0000000000000069)
   ExceptionCode: e0000001
  ExceptionFlags: 00000001
NumberParameters: 0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should ask to the developers https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/